# jTable only displays first record from model

Tags: java, jtable

I have migrated from C# to java, so I'm a novice in java technologies.

I'm trying to populate data from *SQLSERVER* to *jTable*, using **DefaultTableModel**. Code is here.

```
public class mainScreen extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public mainScreen() {
    initComponents();

    try {  
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
        "databaseName=Northwind;user=im;password=123;";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        // SQL query command
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM Products";
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        ResultSetMetaData mtd=rs.getMetaData();
        int columns=mtd.getColumnCount();
        Vector columnName=new Vector();
        Vector DataRows=new Vector();
        DefaultTableModel dtm=new DefaultTableModel();

        for(int i=1; i<columns; i++)
        {
            columnName.addElement(mtd.getColumnName(i));
        }
        dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columnName);

        while (rs.next()) {
         for(int j=1; j<columns; j++){
              DataRows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
              //System.out.println(rs.getString(j));
         }
        }
        Enumeration e= DataRows.elements();
        while(e.hasMoreElements())
        {
               System.out.println(e.nextElement());
        }
        dtm.addRow(DataRows);

        myTable.setModel(dtm);
        dtm.fireTableDataChanged();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
        System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());
    }
}
```

The problem is that this only displays the first row. Anyone can guide me regarding that?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple bugs in your code

check your while loop

```
while(rs.next())
```

if it is ending at the right point

you keep adding elements to the same DataRow. That is not creating a new row for your table.